# Sandbox Web Services

Tags: sandbox-solution

I've been tasked to create a solution that deploys to both SharePoint 2010 and 2013 without the need to "rewrite" what was written for SharePoint 2010 (default deployment path).

Now, as I'm a developer very familiar with farm solutions and building features that does an array of things, like deploying ASMX / WCF services, as well as web.config binding entries and so forth on feature activate am kind of bummed to learn that for this particular requirement I have to stick to sandbox solutions, purely because the clients might or might not be hosted in multi-tenant environments, so it makes sense to stick to sandbox.

My problem is, that the feature I developed for SharePoint 2010 (.Net 3.5) is a farm solution and I have absolutely NO idea how to replicate a particular part of the solution for deployment as a sandbox.

So background:

A 3rd party application needs to submit data to a web service, that connects and inserts data into SharePoint. The 3rd party assembly must be provider agnostic, so I needed to create an intermediate service for this 3rd party application to send me a JSON string and then I, on the SharePoint side do what I need to do. Because this needs to be deployed by an administrator, to bring down the amount of manual deployments, all required files are in my solution feature, including a simple ASMX service to handle the 3rd party calls.

Now, rebuilding the basic component structure as a sandbox is quite easy, my issue is the service. Most of the examples I've seen on the net uses a simple ASPX page to return data via JavaScript, but I cannot find an example of a READ/WRITE service using a sandbox solution. The requirement is that the web service must be deployed with the feature, regardless of whether it's sandbox or solution based.

My question, is this possible? If so, any documentation I can read up on? I've search low and high on Google and it's not my friend today.

Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to deploy a Web Service as part of a Sandbox solution.

Sandboxed solutions can't provision anything directly to IIS/File system.

If you need a solution which will work similar with both SharePoint 2010 and 2013 then your best option would be to host the Web Service completely outside SharePoint (could be on Azure or your own servers) and then have it access SharePoint using the Client Side Object model. For this to work with 2010 you unfortunately have to connect to SharePoint using a Username/Password which you'll have to store somewhere.

Comment: thank you, i thought as much but wanted to confirm.

Comment: Hi, i was also seraching the same for office online 365